# Making multiple directories in python3

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, error-handling, directory

I'm trying to make multiple directories in python but it's saying the file doesn't exist even though I just created it above the code is below, help would be much appreciated.

```
import os
import shutil

# err
if os.path.isdir(r'\Users\Oran\Documents\Sync\Files\Projects/testProject'):

    shutil.rmtree(r'\Users\Oran\Documents\Sync\Files\Projects/testProject')


# Main
os.chdir(r'\Users\Oran\Documents\Sync\Files\Projects')
os.mkdir('testProject')
os.chdir('testProject')
f = open("index.html", "wt")


dir_names = ["assets", "css"]
for x in (dir_names):
os.mkdir(x)

os.chdir('css/')
f = open("index.css", "wt")

os.chdir('assets/')

dir_names = ["img", "css", "js"]
for x in (dir_names):
os.mkdir(x)

os.chdir('js/')
f = open("index.js", "wt")
```

---

### Output

```
[Running] python         
"c:\Users\Oran\Documents\Sync\Files\Projects\PYProjetCreator\index.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
File 
"c:\Users\Oran\Documents\Sync\Files\Projects\PYProjetCreator\index.py", line 
24, in <module>
os.chdir('assets/')
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 
'assets/'

[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.089 seconds
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to change directories into the `testProject/css/assets` folder instead of the `testProject/assets` folder.

The quickest way to get there from the `css` folder is with something like `os.chdir('..\assets')`, though there are lots of other ways to maneuver using [os.pardir](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.pardir) and other [os.path](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html) manipulations.